# A Question about Conditional Problability with a Joint PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Please consider the problem below and my attempt to solve it.
Problem:
Consider a bivariate r.v $(X,Y)$ with joint pdf
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{XY}(x,y) &=& \frac{1}{2\pi \sigma^2}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/(2\sigma^2))}
 \,\,\,\, -\infty < x, y < \infty\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Find $P[(X,Y)| x^2 + y^2 \leq a^2 ]$.
Answer:
Let $K = \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{XY}(x,y) &=& \frac{K}{\pi}e^{-K(x^2+y^2))}
\,\,\,\, -\infty < x, y < \infty \\
P( x^2 + y^2 < a^2 ) &=&
 \int_{-a}^{a} \int_{-\sqrt{ a^2 - y^2 } }^{ \sqrt{ a^2 - y^2 } }
  \frac{K}{\pi}e^{-K(x^2+y^2))} \, dy \, dx \\
P( x^2 + y^2 < a^2 ) &=&
  \int_{-a}^{a} \frac{-1}{\pi}e^{-K(x^2+y^2)}
   \Big|_{y = -\sqrt{a^2 - x^2} }^{ y = \sqrt{a^2 - x^2} } \, dx \\
P( x^2 + y^2 < a^2 ) &=&
 \int_{-a}^{a} \frac{-1}{\pi}e^{-K(x^2 + a^2 - x^2)} +
 \frac{1}{\pi}e^{-K(x^2 - (a^2 - x^2 )))} \\
P( x^2 + y^2 < a^2 ) &=& \int_{-a}^{a} \frac{e^{-K(2x^2-a^2)} - e^{-Ka^2})}{\pi} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Based upon the group's comments I have updated my post.
Now, I will try again using polar coordinates.
Let $K = \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{XY}(x,y) &=& \frac{K}{\pi}e^{-K(x^2+y^2))}
 \,\,\,\, -\infty < x, y < \infty \\
P( x^2 + y^2 < a^2 ) &=&
 \int_{-a}^{a} \int_{-\sqrt{ a^2 - y^2 } }^{ \sqrt{ a^2 - y^2 } }
 \frac{K}{\pi}e^{-K(x^2+y^2))} \, dy \, dx \\
P( x^2 + y^2 < a^2 ) &=&
 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \int_{0 }^{ a }
 \frac{K}{\pi}e^{-K(r^2))} r \, dr \, d\theta \\
P( x^2 + y^2 < a^2 ) &=&
 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} -\frac{1}{2\pi}e^ {-Kr^2 } \Big|_{r = 0}^{r = a} \, d\theta \\
P( x^2 + y^2 < a^2 ) &=&
 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} -\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-Ka^2} + \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{0} \, d\theta \\
P( x^2 + y^2 < a^2 ) &=&
 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1}{2\pi}(1 - e^{-Ka^2} ) \,  d\theta \\
P( x^2 + y^2 < a^2 ) &=& 1 - e^{-Ka^2} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, I realize what the book is asking. So, we have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
P[(X,Y)| x^2 + y^2 \leq a^2 ] &=& P( x^2 + y^2 < a^2 ) \\
P[(X,Y)| x^2 + y^2 \leq a^2 ] &=& 1 - e^{-\frac{a^2}{2 \sigma^2}} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
This is the answer in the back of the book. Therefore, I feel I have done it correctly. I am hoping somebody could confirm that my answer is correct.
Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Polar transformation looks natural here. Or one may say that $(X,Y)$ are independent $\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$ variables, so that $X^2+Y^2$ would have some scaled $\chi^2_2$ distribution. Then you are looking at its distribution function.

Comment: It seems almost certain that the intent of this exercise was for you to use polar coordinates. This is the usual trick by which one finds out the constant factor is $1/(2\pi\sigma^2)$ in the first place.

Comment: @stubbornAtom Are you saying that X and Y are normally distributed independent random variables?

Comment: Yes they are...

Comment: @stubbornAtom I updated my post based upon your comments.